# Connection to PSQL RDS instance via a lambda function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I'm using AWS and trying to connect to my PSQL RDS instance when the lambda function runs. I'm using the pg npm module and this is my code :

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  "use strict"
  const pg = require('pg');
  const connectionStr = "dbstr";
  var client = new pg.Client(connectionStr);
  client.connect(function(err){
    if(err) {
      callback(err)
    }
    callback(null, 'Connection established');
  });
};
```

I've been researching for ages how to do it, but I can't really find anything specific. I've added an IAM role that allows VPC access for my lambda, like what it says in the aws tutorial and I've even set all traffic in my VPC security group, but I still keep getting timeout errors like this:

"errorMessage": "2017-01-22T16:11:21.969Z 544e7fc4-e0bd-11e6-87e6-071c13fc2fc8 Task timed out after 30.00 seconds"

I've tested my function locally and it works fine in connecting to the DB and doing what I want to, but the lamda doesn't do it, and I'm not too sure why.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I've just solved it. Adding:

```
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
```

in your lambda function fixed it for me

Comment: I had the same issue and this fixed it for me too. Any idea why? I'm wondering where else I would have to add this.

Comment: It is a specific problem to lambda where it defaults to waiting until the event loop is empty before the callback is called. This ensures it doesn't wait for the event loop to empty and finishes when you call the callback. You should only need it when doing anything async as I understand